# spring-xd custom modules deployments with redis

Tags: spring-xd

I am working on spring xd and gemfire xd where I have requirement, I collect data from one of the node(local file system) where xd-admin is runnin. I want to collect this file and send for the processing. The below is my stream definition.

source file /tmp/xd/input --ref true | processor(messageCollector) | processor((equation calc) | sink(gemfire xd)

I have 3 nodes spring xd and gemfire xd cluster. first node(xd-admin.xd-container) and 2 & 3 node xd-containers running. containers are registered with xd-admin properly. I configured single redis instance.

My requirement is, I want collect my data from file and send for the process and store to gemfire xd.

messageCollector --> collect all the messages as HashMap and send to the next processor Equation calc, here all the records will go through the equations  and get calculated and results will send to the next sink(gemfire xd) insertion.

This, I have tested in single node env and working good. Now, I moved to distributed env as explained above.

How should I create modules in distributed env. Do I need to move all my modules to all the nodes available.

or

source module will be there only in where the actual file and rest of the modules goes to all the container available.

here, in equation calculator module, I am maintaining a sequence to the each and every record in side the file. and same sequence should be maintained in gemgire xd(sink) as it is.

Since now it is in single node env, it is working good as entire thing processed by single node.

Now, I moved to distributed env where I have no of containers as explained above. How to retain my sequence till insertion.

Please help me with modules deployments in distributed environment.

Thanks,
-Suyodha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `criteria` in the [deployment manifest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#deployment-manifest) to direct your file source to a specific node. Use `count` to deploy your processor(s) to multiple nodes.

However, you can't maintain sequence once you do this. If you only have 1 instance of the second processor, everything will go through it, but the sequence might not be the original sequence from the file(s).

Comment: Gary, I will configure this and let you know the results. Really very helpful information Gary. We are exploring all the components from Spring XD(Integration) re-sequencer, aggregator, pub-sub. Now we moved to distributed environment where maintaining the sequence is key requirement here. I will let you know the results.Thanks a lot Gary.